# Как можно получить ссылку на свое приложение в Yandex store?

Tags: android, яндекс-store

На работе попросили выяснить subj, не могу найти где ее взять, ведь "веб морды" у яндекса нет.

Подскажите, кто в курсе.Спасибо.

Comment: На какой версии android?

Comment: А какая разница какая версия андройда?
Нужно просто ссылка на свое же приложение.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

yastore://details?id=ИМЯ.ПАКЕТА

Answer (score 0):

А спросить у Яндекса не пробовали?

Там наверняка какой-нибудь кастомный URL типа: `ymarket://details?id=ru.mypackage.myapp`, который понимается яндексОвым маркетом. Например, у Амазона что-то типа: `amzn://apps/android?p=ru.mypackage.myapp`, а у Google: `market://details?id=ru.mypackage.myapp`

Второй вариант, который приходит на ум это покопаться в недрах [AppDF](http://www.onepf.org/) - опенсорсная приблуда, которая используется Yandex Store для публикации приложений - может там чего найдется. Очень сильно, правда, сомневаюсь в этом.